# Why exactly are we using Parceable/Serializable?

Tags: java, android

They are used for marshalling/unmarshalling of objects. If we google we get the first result as above. But so far I created classes without implement those.So am I coding it wrong or missing something? Also, where should I use them  exactly?

Comment: Use them if you need to marshall objects. Don't use them if you don't.

Comment: If you don't know what is it for and never encountered a situation where you need to make use of it then don't bother. Just relax  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why exactly are we using Parceable/Serializable?

Many apps have no custom `Parcelable` or `Serializable` classes.

> So am I coding it wrong or missing something?

Probably not.

> Also, where should I use them exactly?

In general, I suspect that you can live a long and happy life never implementing `Parcelable` or `Serializable`.

With respect to `Parcelable`, that is an interface for making objects whose contents can be passed across process boundaries (from app to app or from app to the OS). Many framework classes, like `Intent` and `Bundle` are `Parcelable`. Some developers create custom `Parcelable` classes for things like:

- `onSaveInstanceState()`
- `Intent` extras for passing data between activities
- parameters and return values for AIDL-defined interfaces for binding services across processes

Personally, I try to avoid this, as [there are some risks when using custom `Parcelable` classes](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/07/22/be-careful-where-you-use-custom-parcelables.html).

`Serializable` is a legacy Java mechanism for making objects that can be saved to disk and restored later on. AFAIK, it is generally frowned upon nowadays in Java circles, as there are better data storage solutions. In terms of passing objects between processes, `Serializable` can be used pretty much anywhere `Parcelable` can. `Parcelable` is faster, so unless you are looking for the ancient data storage support, prefer `Parcelable` to `Serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

Parcelables are preferred over Serializable. [Parcelables](http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/) are meant for passing an object between activities. Mind you setting up a Parcelable can be a pain so library's like [Parceler](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler) are great tools.